# Dataset of lecture videos together with transcript

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, dataset, nlp

Where can I find a dataset of lecture videos together with transcripts and perhaps notes? I have a machine learning project that require these but I can't seem to find any existing datasets of lecture videos together with transcripts. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you check kaggle? I'm sure they've got some

Answer (score 0):

Courseras course "Machine learning foundations: a case study approach"  will provide you videos, pdfs with the notes and contents, ipython notebooks(now called Jypyter notebook) as well as practical exercises, and of course, datasets to these exercises:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question, I don't mean videos _about_ machine learning. I meant lecture videos and transcript as a _dataset_

Comment: O sorry, yes,i misunderstood your question. In that case, i dont know if there are any existing datasets ,but maybe you can manually create one by suscriing to some courses and downloading the transcripts. For example stanfords machine learning course(on coursera) and the courses on the data science specialization(by jhon hopkins) have links to download the transcripts.